# Adding time durations together with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, difference

I have a form that allows people to enter different lengths of time, for example:

```
input.time1 = "19:00"
input.time2 = "2:30"
input.time3 = "0:30"
```

I need to add those 3 times together and then subtract it from a base value I have (21:00).

```
$base = "21:00"
```

Then I need something like this:

```
$total = $time1 + $time2 + $time3; //equals 22:00
$base  = "21:00"; // set value
$diff  = $base - $total; // 21:00 - 22:00 = -1:00(mm:ss)
```

Hope this all makes sense, please let me know if I need to explain anything in better detail. Thank you!

Comment: Show the code you've written so far and explain why it does not do what you want.

Comment: Use the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class for this.

Comment: Then you need to total another time from the added time ?

Comment: Write a simple little function that can turn `2:30` into `150` (minutes/seconds) and back again, then work by adding those values.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I'd add [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to that toolbox as well.

Answer (score -1):

To Add 3 Times You should do

```
<?php
$time = "19:00";
$time2 = "2:30";
$time3 = "0:30";
$secs = strtotime($time2)-strtotime("00:00");
$secs1 = strtotime($time3)-strtotime("00:00");
$result = date("H:i",strtotime($time)+$secs+$secs1);
echo $result;
```

Now `$result` will have the addd value,

To subtract another value from the added value

```
$base  = "21:00";
$TimeStart = strtotime($result);
$TimeEnd = strtotime($base);
$Difference = ($TimeEnd - $TimeStart);
echo gmdate("H:i", $Difference);
```

Comment: Don't use timestamp functions to deal with intervals. At the very least you can run into fun little bugs with daylight saving times.

Comment: @deceze Ok Thanks, May i know how can i check it ?

Answer (score -1):

`$base = strtotime('21:00');`
`$total = strtotime($time1)+strtotime($time2);+strtotime($time3)`
`$diff = date("H:i", strtotime("$total - $base"));`

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -2):

The quick and dirty example do-it-yourself method:

```
function string_to_int($time) {
    list($minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time);
    return $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

function int_to_string($seconds) {
    return sprintf('%d:%02d', floor($seconds / 60), $seconds % 60);
}

$duration = string_to_int('19:00') + string_to_int('2:30') + string_to_int('0:30');
echo int_to_string($duration);
```

You convert `xx:yy` to an integer of whole seconds, sum them, then format that back into `xx:yy` for human readable output.